# Twitter bootstrap nested column

Tags: twitter, nested

Hi please look at this,

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-5"></div>
<div class="col-lg-15">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-**2/3**"></div>
<div class="col-lg-**1/3**"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

How Can I do it without separator?
I would like to do something like that:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-10"></div>
<div class="col-lg-5"></div>
</div>
```

This is Grid - 20 columns, 5 column sidebar 15 rest.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is based on a 12 column grid.  If you want a column to be 2/3's of a page with a sidebar 1/3 I would do the following.

```
<div class="container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <p> This content is 2/3 of the page</p>
    </div><!-- col-sm-8 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 -->
      <p>This content is 1/3 of the page</p>
    </div><!-- col-sm-4 -->
  </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- container -->
```

If you are wanting it to be responsive I would start with defining the smaller screen size "col-sm-?" and large screens will inherit this.

Otherwise, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve and what you mean by separator.  Could you clarify?

Hope this helps.